# Copy user session when anonymous user logs in with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I know that `flask.session` can be used to store session data with `session['key'] = value`, but I'm not sure I can do this when using Flask-Login.  My application is a shopping cart, and I want to make sure the cart is moved to the logged in user if they add something as an anonymous user first.  I also want to clear the session when the user logs out.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Login doesn't do anything to change how you use the session.  You still use the session as you normally would.

```
from flask import session
session['my_key'] = my_value  # add value
del session['my_key']  # remove value
session.clear()  # remove everything
```

The session may just persist after login.  If you find it doesn't, you can copy the session during login, login, then restore the data.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    old_session = session.copy()
    ...
    login_user(user)
    session.update(old_session)
    ...
```

You can clear the session in the logout endpoint.  If the user does not log out, but just closes the browser, there's no way to clear the session, you just have to rely on it expiring.

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    ...
```